# select courses having sum of duration less than 20 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to select a list of courses from a table which are having names and durations.

Select the list such that all the courses having sum of their duration below 20 hours as well as all the courses which are remaining in the table separately.

When comes to courses which are between 20 hours i.e. when a course comes between 19 hours and 23 hours with duration 4 hours I need to select that into the 1st category.
I have tried the below code but it is not considering the course that falls between both side of 20 hours.

```
SELECT ID,
       Course 
FROM
    (
        SELECT a.ID,
               a.COURSE,
               a.DURATION,
               SUM(b.DURATION)  CUM_SUM 
        FROM #TempTable a JOIN #TempTable b ON a.ID >= b.ID 
        GROUP BY a.ID,a.COURSE,a.DURATION 
    ) temp 
WHERE CUM_SUM <=20
```

How can I get the courses that fall between the considered limit into the category I need to select?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Duration` from your sub-select, and get only the `SUM`:

```
SELECT ID,
       Course 
FROM
    (
        SELECT a.ID,
               a.COURSE,
               SUM(b.DURATION)  CUM_SUM 
        FROM #TempTable a JOIN #TempTable b ON a.ID >= b.ID 
        GROUP BY a.ID,a.COURSE
    ) temp 
WHERE CUM_SUM <=20
```